# How to flip an object in LimeJS?

Tags: html, limejs

I am new to game development.I have to flip an object when i click on the object.How can we solve this issue in LimeJS for HTML5.

Comment: I stuck at start buddy i am new to this LimeJs.COULD you help me out. @Mitch Wheat

Comment: that's what google is for....

Comment: i am searching for the same.But i didn't found any source to know about flipping so far @Mitch Wheat

Comment: What do you mean "flip" it? Mirror the object's graphics across the x or y axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe http://limejs.digitalfruit.ee/docs/symbols/lime.animation.RotateBy.html is what you're looking for, if not try to look around at the other animation documentations.